# How can I reload a page after routing to another page using Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm developing a demo website using Meteor js. I want to click a button and go to another page directly. But after that, the new page needs to be reloaded automatically. The logic is like this:

```
Template.reload.events({
  'click #mybutton': function(){
     var index = ...//randomly generate an index;
     Router.go('/'+index);//I have Router.route("/:index" ) in router.js
     //I want to reload the new page after the going to a new page
  }
```

I think I can use `document.location.reload(true);` somewhere but I'm not sure where to put it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page? Sounds like XY problem.

Comment: Because there're some texts displayed on the page and the user can add more or delete some. If I don't reload the page, the texts from last 'index' will persists when the new one load. I'm not so sure about the exact reason but I found out 'reloading' the page will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please
You can use the Location.reload() method.

```
Template.reload.events({
  'click #mybutton': function(){
     var index = ...//randomly generate an index;
     Router.go('/'+index);//I have Router.route("/:index" ) in router.js
     document.location.reload(true);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, it works. Here's one thing: there's another function in my program is to change some texts on the page and update the change in the collection (I use Autoform here). I found that if I implement code like what you suggest, it works well if I don't change the text on the page. But if I do, and click `#mybutton` after that, it reload the original page. Only when I click the button again, it goes to a random page and then reload it. Do you know what the reason might be and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @yiyizheliu please open a new question with all details and don't forget to add your codes like php, html, js or etc. ok ?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi here's my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821872/contents-from-previous-page-persist-when-routed-to-a-new-one-meteor. Could you take a look at it? Thanks a lot